# Trying to send an email on last row of sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send an email based on the last row with data in a google sheet. I am currently getting

undefined submitted a time off request
From: undefined undefined
To: undefined undefined

here is my script. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function sendEmail() {
  // Load the sheet that contains the birthdays.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Responses");
  var row = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var name = row[1];
  var startDate = row[3];
  var startTime = row[4];
  var endDate = row[5];
  var endTime = row[6];
  var subject = name + " submitted a time off request";
  var recipient = "john.doe@gmail.com";
  var body = name + " submitted a time off request \nFrom: " + startDate + " " + startTime + "\nTo: " + endDate + " " + endTime;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
  const vs = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  const name = vs[1];
  const startDate = vs[3];
  const startTime = vs[4];
  const endDate = vs[5];
  const endTime = vs[6];
  const subject = name + " submitted a time off request";
  const recipient = "john.doe@gmail.com";
  const body = name + " submitted a time off request \nFrom: " + startDate + " " + startTime + "\nTo: " + endDate + " " + endTime;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: now it just shows blanks where one would expect values

Comment: I think I have an issue with it detecting data where there is none. I believe I have a work around. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you add the [0] at the end of the 4th line?

Comment: Can you share a working example at the bottom of your question?

Comment: It is exactly your solution. It was an issue with the data on the sheet it self. I just had to create a new sheet and use a query to filter out not applicable data.